# Vue js, missing mapping from HTML to related JS

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js, model-view-controller

There is something missing in my spring boot application. I am trying to follow the very first steps of the official Vue documentation in order to create the simplest Vue application possible. What I have is the current scenario:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String index() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

and inside the Resource folder I have created a Template folder in which my **home.html** and **home.js** are defined as:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
```

The problem is that when I try to access the `_home_` route the message showing is

`{{ message }}`

so for some reason the `js` is not linked properly. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code in this snippet it seems to work fine:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

Are you seeing any errors in the dev tools console? Also, add some logs inside your `js` file to make sure it's executing at all.

Comment: yes, it seems it cannot load the resource. I created a testing button that from my html point to a function in the js.. the IDE sees the function correctly and its implementation. However when I run the application it says it fails loading that js.. you think there is a problem with the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your `home.html` is not configured to use Vue via CDN correctly. Whilst it does load Vue via CDN, it does not specify that it needs to load `home.js` and setup the Vue instance.

Without diving into Spring Boot specifics for serving resources (e.g. `home.js`) as it's not the root cause of the problem, update `home.html` to embed the script:

```html
<!-- Note this is Vue 2 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
</script>
```

Notice that if you open `home.html` now in your browser it will work. Thus it will also work when Spring Boot serves it.